# Hover function does not work in headless mode (selenium python)

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, hover, headless

I am trying to access an element(named regis in the code) that is clickable only after hovering over another element.
The code works in normal mode but when I run chrome in headless mode it can not find the element (regis).
Attached is the snapshot of the code.
Thanks in advance.

Error encountered:

" regis = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Individual Registration').
File " ", line 428, in find_element_by_link_text
return self.find_element(by=By.LINK_TEXT, value=link_text).
File "", line 976, in find_element.
return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {.
File "", line 321, in execute.
self.error_handler.check_response(response).
File " ", line 242, in check_response.
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"link text","selector":"Individual Registration"}
(Session info: headless chrome= xyzzy )"

```
***element_to_hover_over = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="services"]/a')
hover = ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element_to_hover_over)
hover.perform()
regis = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Individual Registration')
regis.click()***
```

Comment: Please include the full error traceback in your question.

Comment: @MikeScotty sure.